# Agrupar valor de um array em PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [anomes] => 201601
        [codreg] => 41
        [nomreg] => PR
        [codcin] => 1
        [nomcin] => OUTROS
        [valven] => 6835.7000
        [qtdven] => 1078.8000
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [anomes] => 201601
        [codreg] => 42
        [nomreg] => SC
        [codcin] => 1
        [nomcin] => OUTROS
        [valven] => 3129.0000
        [qtdven] => 366.6200
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [anomes] => 201601
        [codreg] => 42
        [nomreg] => SC
        [codcin] => 2
        [nomcin] => PECAS
        [valven] => 346.9100
        [qtdven] => 73.6600
    )

)
```

e gostaria de agrupá-lo pelo codreg, implementei o seguinte:

```
$saida    = array();

foreach ($dadf513 as $row) {

    if(!isset($saida[$row->nomreg])) {
        $saida[$row->nomreg] = array(floatval($row->valven));
    } else {
        array_push($saida[$row->nomreg], floatval($row->valven));
    }

    $arrayFinal[$row->nomreg] = [
        'name' => $row->nomreg,
        'data' => $saida[$row->nomreg]
    ];
}
print_r($arrayFinal);
```

e objetive o resultado:

```
Array
(
[PR] => Array
    (
        [name] => PR
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 6835.7
            )

    )

[SC] => Array
    (
        [name] => SC
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3129
                [1] => 346.91
            )

    )

)
```

Até aqui beleza, minha dúvida é a seguinte, como passar o valor 0 no [data], quando não existir nenhum valor? Para ficar da seguinte forma:

```
Array
(
[PR] => Array
    (
        [name] => PR
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 6835.7
                [1] => 0
            )

    )

[SC] => Array
    (
        [name] => SC
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3129
                [1] => 346.91
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: Não ficou claro qual é a relação do seu agrupamento, me parece que houve mais alterações do que apenas fazer um `map` agrupando pelo código.

Comment: @IsraelMerljak o array inicial é resultado de um select do banco, depois disso fiz o code abaixo

Comment: A pergunta não está muito clara. O que acontece se tiver 3 objetos com `SC` e 1 `PR` ? O que acontece se tiver 3 `SC`  2 `PR` e outro distinto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Primeira Opção

Não ficou muito claro o que você deseja, e a transformação dos dados originais para o seu array "filtrado" não me pareceu exatamente o que você deseja pela sua descrição. Creio que o resultado que você procura seja algo assim:

```
Array (
    [41] => Array ( // Agrupa todos com codreg 41
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [anomes] => 201601
            [codreg] => 41
            [nomreg] => PR
            [codcin] => 1
            [nomcin] => OUTROS
            [valven] => 6835.7000
            [qtdven] => 1078.8000
        )
    )
    [42] => Array ( //agrupa todos com codreg 42
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [anomes] => 201601
            [codreg] => 42
            [nomreg] => SC
            [codcin] => 1
            [nomcin] => OUTROS
            [valven] => 3129.0000
            [qtdven] => 366.6200
        )

        [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [anomes] => 201601
            [codreg] => 42
            [nomreg] => SC
            [codcin] => 2
            [nomcin] => PECAS
            [valven] => 346.9100
            [qtdven] => 73.6600
        )
    )
)
```

Para tal você precisaria de uma função assim:

```
function groupByCodReg($inputArray) {
    $resultMap = [];

    foreach($inputArray as $data) {
        if(!isset($resultMap[$data->codreg])) {
            $resultMap[$data->codreg] = []; 
        }

        $resultMap[$data->codreg][] = $data;    
    }

    return $resultMap;
}
```

---

## Segunda Opção

Talvez o que você queira é agregar os valores dos arrays em uma chave comum para utilizar em algum gráfico. Daí faria sentido o que você tentou fazer com os dados. 
Dessa forma o resultado esperado seria assim:

```
array(2) {
    ["PR"]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> float(6835.7)
        [1]=> float(0)
    }
    ["SC"]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> float(3129)
        [1]=> float(346.91)
    }
}
```

Para tal você poderia utilizar algo tipo:

```
function aggregateValvenByNomreg($inputArray) {
    $resultMap = [];

    foreach($inputArray as $data) {
        if(!isset($resultMap[$data->nomreg])) {
            $resultMap[$data->nomreg] = [];
        }

        $resultMap[$data->nomreg][] = $data->valven;
    }

    // completa arrays com 0
    $maiorComprimento = getLengthier($resultMap);
    foreach($resultMap as $key => $value) {
        while(count($resultMap[$key]) < $maiorComprimento) {
            $resultMap[$key][] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    return $resultMap;
}

function getLengthier($array) {
    $max = 0;

    foreach($array as $data) {
        $length = count($data);
        if($length > $max) $max = $length;
    }

    return $max;
}
```

> Segue um link do Repl.it com o código funcionando para você verificar.
>   [>>ExemploAqui<<](https://repl.it/@IsraelMerljak/StckOvrFlwArrayToMap)

Answer (score 2):

Tendo uma variável com a `array` desejada, chamando de `$input`, você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($input as $value)
  $arr[$value->nomreg][] = isset($value->valven) ? $value->valven : 0;
```

Dessa forma, seu resultado sairia mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
array(2) {
  ["PR"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["SC"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(3129)
    [1]=>
    float(346.91)
  }
}
```

Para acessar os dados:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  // $key irá retorna a chave/name - por exemplo "PR" e "SC"
  // $value irá retornar os valores 
}
```

A `array` gerada teria um padrão um pouco diferente do que o mostrado por você, mas seria gerado de forma mais simples e fácil, e ainda permitindo você ter os mesmo dados, com fácil acesso.